# How does Google implement "Undo" in GMail?

Tags: web-applications, undo

I've read about [how to implement Undo in web applications](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/undo-made-easy-with-ajax-part-1/). There are several drawbacks to this light-weight approach on the client-side.

Does anyone know how Google implements "Undo" in their apps, e.g. GMail? Is it a client-side implementation like Aza Raskin's solution? Is it some kind of "Delete" record in a DB that gets removed again? Or something entirely different?

Comment: Of course, it depends. Sometimes a client-side solution is enough, but most of the time it's server-side: a database entry is only marked as deleted, not physically removed.

Comment: I know! That's why I wanted to know: How does Google do it in GMail?

Answer (score 1):

Blog below explain how it is done using python.
Credit to Alexandre Bourget for putting it up

http://blog.abourget.net/2010/2/20/gmail-undo-cancel-feature-introducing-python-webundo/

Answer (score 0):

They probably delay the actual sending of the email for a set amount of time where you have a chance to cancel it.